# Java AVL Tree Problems

Tags: java, avl-tree

I'm trying to build an AVL tree in Java, but I'm having trouble with updating heights after the rotations. Here is the code I'm having trouble with.

```
 public void checkHeights(Node<T> u) {
  if (u == nil) return;
  checkHeights(u.left);
  checkHeights(u.right);
  System.out.println(u.h);
  if (height(u) != 1 + Math.max(height(u.left), height(u.right)))
   throw new RuntimeException("Check heights shows incorrect heights");
  int dif = height(u.left) - height(u.right);
  if (dif < -1 || dif > 1)
   throw new RuntimeException("Check heights found height difference of " + dif);
 }

 /**
  * Fix up
  * @param u
  */
 public void fixup(Node<T> u) {
  while (u != nil) {
   int dif = height(u.left) - height(u.right);
   if(debug)System.out.println("Node dif at " + u.x + " is: " + dif);
   if (dif > 1) {
     if(debug)System.out.println("u.left is larger");
     if(height(u.left.left) - height(u.left.right) < 0) {
       if(debug)System.out.println("u.left dif is: " + (height(u.left.left) - height(u.left.right)));
       rotateLeft(u.left);
     }
     rotateRight(u);

   } else if (dif < -1) {
     if(debug)System.out.println("u.right is larger");
     if(height(u.right.left) - height(u.right.right) > 0) {
       if(debug)System.out.println("u.right dif is: " + (height(u.right.left) - height(u.right.right)));
       rotateRight(u.right);
     }
     rotateLeft(u);
   }
   if(debug) System.out.println("Height of " + u.x + " is " + height(u));
   u = u.parent;
  }
 }

 public void rotateLeft(Node<T> u) {
  super.rotateLeft(u);
  u.h = Math.max(height(u.left), height(u.right)) + 1;
  u.parent.h = Math.max(height(u.parent.left), height(u.parent.right)) + 1;
  if(debug)System.out.println("After left rotation, " + u.x + " has height " + u.h + " and " + u.parent.x + " has height " + u.parent.h);
 }

 public void rotateRight(Node<T> u) {
  super.rotateRight(u);
  u.h = Math.max(height(u.left), height(u.right)) + 1;
  u.parent.h = Math.max(height(u.parent.left), height(u.parent.right)) + 1;
  if(debug)System.out.println("After right rotation, " + u.x + " has height " + u.h + " and " + u.parent.x + " has height " + u.parent.h);
 }
```

I've done a bunch of unit tests, and I keep getting checkHeights throwing exceptions. I'm almost positive that what's going on is the when a rotation occurs at a depth greater than 2, the heights aren't updated recursively up the tree. For example, if I add values from 0 to 10 in, the first left rotation occurs no problem and the values get their right heights, but when I try to rotate lower down, the parent nodes aren't accurately update to their new heights, causing the exceptions to be thrown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: The one that is thrown in checkHeights, RuntimeException, whenever the heights are no longer correct. I should mention that in the unit tests I'm recursively testing the nodes to ensure their height field is in fact their height.

Comment: 1st or 2nd exception?

Comment: Ah sorry, busy day, first one